# Unable to Change Font Size in BeeWare Label

Tags: python, android, user-interface, beeware

I'm building my first **BeeWare** app. The app itself is destined for an **Android** device, and I'm developing it on a **Linux** (Ubuntu) machine.

My problem is fairly straightforward, but no less infuriating. **I can't seem to increase the font size within any given `Label` widget.** This is what my app.py file looks like:

```py
import toga
from toga.fonts import Font, SANS_SERIF
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW

class Charon(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))

        title_label = toga.Label("Hello, world!")
        title_label.font = Font(family=SANS_SERIF, size=50)

        main_box.add(title_label)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

def main():
    result = Charon()
    return result
```

As per [the tutorial](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-1.html), if I move to the beeware-venv environment and then run `briefcase dev`, the app runs without throwing an exception. However, no matter what I do with the snippet `size=50` - whether I set the font size to 5 or 500 - **the size of the text remains unchanged**. If I run the same code within an Android emulator, I run into the same issue: the font size doesn't change.

Comment: Looking at the [toga Font documentation](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/resources/fonts.html), there's no checkbox for "Android"; that indicates to me that it's not [fully] supported.

Comment: @RandomDavis I too had noticed that. Is there any work around?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not familiar with the library whatsoever, I just googled the documentation. Sounds like something you should ask as a new question, either on here or on a site more specific to that library. Maybe you could raise it as an issue on their GitHub.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks. I'll give that a go, and get back to you here if I come across anything important.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
title_label = toga.Label("Hello, world!")
```

You want to add a style declaration like this:

```
title_label = toga.Label("Hello, world!", style=Pack(font_size=50, font_family=SANS_SERIF))
```

Other supported style properties [here](https://github.com/beeware/toga/blob/main/docs/reference/style/pack.rst).

I am not quite bright enough to understand why the .font attribute as in your example doesn't work, but I can confirm that it doesn't.

Comment: As you can see, it's been quite a while since I asked this question, and I haven't worked with BeeWare since. But if others upvote this answer, then I will accept it.